# TimeoutException when trying to run python selenium webdriver code

Tags: python, selenium

I keep getting this error when trying to run a script on python that will login into my website and do some jobs. I don't have much knowledge about selenium and webdriver so i need help. When it's necessary i can publish the script.

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 73, in spot
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Can you share the page URL ?

Comment: Well, without your code we can't give a complete answer

Comment: also try this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]").click()` this should give the exact error, cause WebDriverWait will always give you `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` also use @ to reply

Answer (score 0):

In following line of code you have added 10 seconds of time out. This line weights for 10 seconds to load the XPath items and after 10 seconds give timeout exception. Try to increase that time.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click()
```

Comment: What if there is an iframe here or if the locator is wrong?

Comment: But this is also the case the locator is correct and it is taking more than 10 seconds to load on page.

Comment: Right, but in most cases it takes less that 10 seconds, so you can not be sure this is the problem here.

Comment: but it could be also.